# bluetooth connection background

Tags: android, bluetooth, background, android-bluetooth

I have developed an app that uses bluetooth connection to communicate with other device. 
When the app goes in background the bluetooth connection is always active, until I really close the app (with the swipe).
Is there a way, if the app is in background, to close the bluetooth connection (bluetooth socket) after, for example, 5 minutes?
Thanks

EDIT

I have created an onPause method:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {

    if(Utility.isAppIsInBackground(MainActivity.this)){

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        bsocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, 10000);
            }
        });

    }



    super.onPause();
}
```

that should close the connectivity after 10 seconds, when the app is in the background.

This is the method:

```
   public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
```

But the timer doesn't start. It is correct?
Thanks

Comment: Check you application status. if application go to pause state or stop state then call disconnect methods of bluetooth connectivity.

Comment: override onPause method of your class to achieve this

Comment: @sumit ok, but what I do in this method? I create a timer that after 5 minutes closes bluetooth application. But if the user re-open the app before the 5 minutes?

Comment: then nothing just create a handler there and give initial timeout 5 mins and initialize your bluetooth adaptor inside your application onResume. that will solve your problem

Comment: @sumit please look my edit